# Why does a neutral atom not have a dipole moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, dipole-moment

I wonder why a single atom has no outward dipole moment, the electron in the hydrogen atom is everywhere at the same time, with a different probability of finding it at any point within the 1s orbital, because the orbital is spherically symmetrical, all dipole directions would always cancel each other out.

But if I look at the atom from one side, one dipole would always be closer to me than the one on the other side of the atom (I mean the electron that lies point-symmetrically to the core on the other side.) so I would still feel this, "cancelling" in that sense doesn't really exist, it's more about feeling the repulsion of one dipole and the attraction of the other.

Perhaps you can also call my question, why is an atom which has 1 proton and 1 electron neutral, since for example another electron fits into the $\rm H$ atom in the 1s orbital, which also has the same energy level as the first electron and both would feel the same nuclear force?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a spherical symmetric negative charge distribution. The electric field outside is equivalent as if all the charge was at the center. It is the same result that is also valid for mass and gravitational field.

Now, if there is an equal amount of positive charge at the center, the resultant external field vanishes.

So, there is no dipole.

Comment: But as an observer from outside, I am always at the stronger dipole, because the side facing me (relative to the nucleus) momentary dipoles are stronger for me than those on the opposite side of the nucleus, or? https://imgur.com/a/pl6iQVS

Comment: No, otherwise the field effect could not be replaced by a point charge. You have to make an integral of the fields generated by all sphere elements.